# Should I edit my answer when the asker edits the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, answers

Let's think on the following scenario:

A user asks a question, including part of his code. I have an idea of what could be the problem, which should be included in a part of code he didn't add. I answer him to do that.

Moments later, I realize extra problems there could be. So I edit my answer, in order to cover all the possibilities.

Finally, the user decides to edit his question, to include some of the code I posted to him, to show he had it already included.

This way, some of the possibilities of my answer become useless, since he showed me he had already done that. Therefore, my answer looks a little bit stupid.

Should I really edit it?

What other options do I have?

Might be worthy to say, my answer has already upvotes and has been accepted by the user.

Comment: Looks fine to me to be honest. I think covering all grounds _even_ if the OP has already done it doesn't make your answer look stupid. Had you not covered all grounds it _may_ have suggested to the OP that they didn't need it and took it out leading to more problems.

Comment: Good chance you answering "chameleon question". Run away is solid strategy in this case.

Comment: The edit history will show that the user edited in those fixes after you answered. Your answer doesn't look stupid.

Comment: I've been known to edit an answer to add a paragraph such as "THIS ANSWER RELATED TO A PREVIOUS VERSION OF THE QUESTION, AND IS NO LONGER RELEVANT BECAUSE THE QUESTION HAS CHANGED". And then start again with a fresh answer if you're still motivated to help the guy.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/175248

Comment: "I have an idea of what could be the problem, which *should be included in a part of code he didn't add*. I **answer** him to do that." You shouldn't do that, you should comment that there's relevant information missing and that it's required.

Comment: Stack answer are intended to help the person at present, and reference for the future, no?  If so, your multiple options may well help others in future, and were still completely valid at the time without the information to show they were covered by the questioner.  I see no reason to remove them if they are valid avenues at the time you wrote the response on that grounds alone.

Comment: What you should do is rollback the question back to it's original form if OP's edit invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's all about correctness and readability, not about how things look or what people might think. If your answer contains faults for whatever reason or is not easy to understand, edit it.

In this scenario sketch however, there is only a little extra information which can be considered superfluous. That might not help the person who asked the question; it may still help someone else by providing a more complete picture. And that is actually the goal of the site - not to have a question of a single person answered, but to answer the question for a great many people at the same time.

I'd say: leave it be.

Comment: With, possibly, an edit to indicate that the OP hadn't _originally_ included certain information in the question so (a) it doesn't look like you didn't read the question, and (b) it will still help someone in the future who might not have the code in question.

Answer (score 4):

First of all: don't worry about looking stupid. It's not that rare to see answers that are well received but apparently are not aligned with the question. In this case I just look at the **history** of the question, and see what the answerer answered to exactly.

As said previously, you could very well leave all possibilities covered in your answer.

Finally, we get to my **actual point** of my answer:

> What other options do I have?

Refrain from answering ambiguous or incomplete questions. Leave a comment requesting all the information needed. Reminding of MCVE couldn't hurt. It's good that you want to help, but trying to guess what the OP should have provided in the first place can lead to a waste of time (yours mainly) and incorrect or irrelevant answers. The scenario you describe is a happy one, where your answer is still valid and useful, but with this strategy it can very easily go the other route.

Also we should encourage users to post complete questions, and one way we can achieve that is to answer only to complete questions.