# Should I edit for this update to my problem?

Tags: support, edits, asking-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How do I synchronize animations on an object using A-frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249179/how-do-i-synchronize-animations-on-an-object-using-a-frame)

I hit two new snags when trying to implement the suggested answer.

1. The `alternate` setting for the `dir` property is not alternating like my original `a-animation` element did before.
2. I can't seem to get the component made in my javascript code to do the `throttle` or `tick` mechanism to work.

Should I edit my post to include the new code changes at the bottom for more help?

Comment: the other way round: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350309/should-i-edit-my-answer-when-the-asker-edits-the-question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for caring about the site's policies and expected behaviors. Thank you for doing the research to locate the correct place to ask about them (Meta), and taking the time to compose a question. We really appreciate your doing this, and wish everyone was as conscientious.

To answer your question:

- **If the answer is unclear, incomplete, or not working as advertised, then use comments under the answer to inform the author and politely ask for them to clarify.** They *should* use this opportunity to edit their answer and fix the problems. They will probably also leave a comment reply.
- **If the answer is fine on its own, and you're just experiencing *follow-up* problems, then you should ask a new (separate) question.** It's fine to include a link to the original Q&A if it helps to provide context, but the expectation is that each question be fully self-contained (not necessary to follow links in order to understand what is being asked), so you'll need to include code that reproduces the problem in the body of the new question itself.

I can't tell you which of these to do in this particular circumstance, because I'm not a web programmer, and thus can't really judge. It is, ultimately, a judgment call that must be made on a case-by-case basis.

Sometimes, you might even start by doing the former, and then realize after a couple of back-and-forth comments that it would be better asked as a new question. You can then go ahead and do that, leaving a link to the new question in the comments as supplemental.

Editing the question should be done to *clarify* your original question, not to fundamentally change or expand it. This is most commonly done in response to comments soliciting clarification from you, or when you aren't getting any feedback at all.

There are limited circumstances where it is okay to make edits that change your question, but, in general, this should be avoided. In particular, it *must* be avoided when it would *invalidate* (render incorrect) any existing answers, because that's simply unfair—don't [move the goal posts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts). Cases where you might make drastic edits are: when you have not yet received any answers, or when your question has been closed (or put "on hold") and you are editing to fix the problems.

Comment: @Peter "doing this" is a gerund phrase, and English grammar requires that nouns preceding gerunds be possessive, so "your" is correct here. That's a really subtle rule, though, and there are arguments that could be made for using "you" instead. Either would be immediately understandable. However, "you're" is completely wrong. That contraction means "you are", so that phrase becomes "We really appreciate you are doing this", which is obviously wrong.